# Gettting an encryption error when attempting to embed a wlst script into a java class

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I'm trying to put together a small utility that will let us pull managed server listen addresses and ports out of the managed servers in a domain.

WLST seemed like the right tool to use.

I've get a script that works something like this

```
admin_url = sys.argv[1]
cluster = sys.argv[2]
connect(url=admin_url)
servers = get_servers(cluster)
for server in servers.values():
  address = server.getListenAddress()
  port = str(server.getListenPort())
  server_url = address + ":" + port
  addresses.append(server_url)
print ','.join(addresses)
```

We're using weblogic keys to store the username and password, so no need to pass connect the username and password. It works fine, but...we need to use this in an ant script, and it looks like the only way to get info out of WLST and back into ant is via capturing the output.

The first problem I ran into is that WLST prints some garbage (a header) when you invoke it that you can't suppress. "Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...", etc.

So a little searching reveals there's no way to suppress that if you invoke WLST directly, but you can embed your script in a java class and the embedded interpreter won't output the header.

I wrapped my script in a class, compiled it and it runs no problem when I run it using java...

```
>java wlst.GetClusterAddress t3://myhost:7001 mycluster

mymanagedserver1:9999,mymananagedserver2:9999
```

So far so good.

Now I try to wrap that class in my ant script...

```
<java classname="wlst.GetClusterAddress" outputproperty="${addresses}" >
  <arg line="${admin.url} ${cluster.name}"/>
  <classpath refid="class.path"/>
</java>
```

Ant throws an exception when connecting to the admin server

```
 [java] WLSTException: Error occured while performing connect : Error connecting to the server : weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException: weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException: [Security:090219]Error decrypting Secret Key java.lang.SecurityException: The provider self-integrity check failed.
 [java] Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace
 [java]
```

I've checked my classpath, and all seems to be the same between java and ant. I'm not sure where to look next. Why doesn't this work when using ant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it when you set fork="true" in the `java` task:

```
<java classname="wlst.GetClusterAddress" outputproperty="${addresses}" fork="true">
...
```

Comment: Woot! That's it. Works like a charm now. Thanks!